# Sudoers file allow sudo on specific file for active directory group

Tags: active-directory, ubuntu-12.04, sudo

I have active directory sign in working on an Ubuntu 12.04 box.  When the user signs in, I have a script that runs that needs sudo permission (since it modifies the samba config file).  How would I specify this in my `sudoers` file?

The active directory user is a part of a group called `domain users`.  I see `domain users` when I issue `groups` as the active directory user.

I've tried:

```
%domain+users ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/userScripts/createSambaShare.php
```

This still asks me for a password and then tells me that the user is not in the `sudoers` file.

Is there a log I can check to see what it's doing when it asks the active directory user for their password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using a plus sign in lieu of the space in `Domain Users`. I don't see any reason why that would work.

Instead, escape the space with a backslash:

```
 %Domain\ Users ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/userScripts/createSambaShare.php
```

If that doesn't work, try using an alias:

```
 User_Alias DomainUsers=%Domain\ Users
 DomainUsers ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/userScripts/createSambaShare.php
```

Also, keep in mind that pretty much everything in Linux is case-sensitive, including user and group names. Is the group really showing up as `domain users`, or is it showing up as `Domain Users`? It has to match.

Comment: It is listed as `domain users` and I guess I thought that was the reason for `winbind separator = +` in my Samba config. Testing now.

Comment: backslash does the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just set the UNIX group in `/etc/sudoers` and then make sure everybody is added to that group in AD?

Comment: You mean do something like `%Programmers ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/createSambaShare.php` ?

Comment: That seems reasonable enough.

Comment: I did that.  My AD user is part of the "Programmers" group in active directory.  Looks like my company has it set up so that the AD Domain Services Folder for the group is `Domain.com/Staff/Security Groups`, does my group in linux then become `%DOMAIN.COM/Staff/Security+Groups/Programmers` ?

Comment: You set up the group in UNIX Attributes, right?

Comment: I would assume not.  I asked our sys admin about the unix tab for each user and he said he didn't see a unix tab, so I'll refer him to your link on my other question.

Comment: Does the link you provided in the last question also affect 2008?

Comment: Try clicking it. :)

Comment: Found the attributes tab, added my user to it.  When I log in to the linux box with my AD user, it still asks for my password.  When I do `groups` with my AD user, I do not see the group `Programmers`.

Comment: Please see my updated question.  I now have a group to work with.